# Vaadin 14.7 does not load css style if I use redirect

Tags: vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I use forwardTo if the user is not logged in on my vaadin 14.7 application in a class that implements VaadinServiceInitListener.

```
if (loggedIn == null || !loggedIn) {
        beforeEnterEvent.forwardTo(LoginView.NAVIGATION_LOGIN);
}
```

The problem is that the theme style in the login page is not loaded, if I reload the login page, the theme is loaded.

Any hint ?

Comment: How are you importing the styles? Are you using Vaadin 14 in legacy bower mode or npm mode ?

Comment: the styles are imported by the new 14.6 theme function.
How do I recognise if running in npm mode ?

Comment: After a check, I'm using npm mode.

Comment: Ok, I see, looks like a possible bug, see also https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/11896

Comment: You are right, it is the same behaviour as mine.

Comment: Are there any workaround that runs?

Comment: The ticket mentions adding @Theme annotation in LoginView ... I have not tried it out myself.

Comment: it did not solve the problem on using forwardTo.

Comment: Well, someone is working on a fix, be patient https://github.com/vaadin/flow/pull/11941

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been fixed in Vaadin 14.7.2